# shadow with blur edges using pure css only

Tags: css

Is there any possibility to make a shadow like this with pure css only?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to achieve that with box-shadow:

```
.shadow {
  -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
  box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
}
```

- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

Answer (score 1):

As the shadow is uneven, I'd try something like this: http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css3-paper-curl/. I know it's not exactly the effect you're going for but you'll have somewhere to start.

Answer (score 1):

A **box shadow** is definitely the way to go for a pure-CSS tapering shadow. But since box shadows follow the contours of the element to which they're applied, a `:before` or `:after` pseudo element would work best (to keep the html uncluttered).

```
.roundShadow:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:90%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:-1;
  margin:0 5%;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  -webkit-border-radius:50% 4%;
  -moz-box-shadow:0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  -moz-border-radius:50% 4%;
  box-shadow:0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  border-radius:50% 4%;
}
```

This creates a block-level pseudo element behind the section that emulates the shape of the parent element, but with a rounded bottom and desired box shadow.

Just add `class="roundShadow"` to the section you want. You may have to tinker with the second figure of the **margin** to keep the shadow centered, but otherwise the shadow should conform to whatever element you stick it on. Oh, and make sure the *parent element* is `position:relative;` or `position:absolute;` or it won't work!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something like this though it won't be as precise a shadow as the one that you have got in your image.

Using CSS3 box shadow you can do something like this:

```
.bottom-shadow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -6px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -6px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -6px #000000;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HP9zQ/2/)

If you're unsure, the order of the parameters for `box-shadow` is:

```
box-shadow: [horizontal-offset] [vertical-offset] [blur] [spread] [colour]
```